# How can I stream video from my Kivy android app to a Server that processes the data?

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language

I'm looking for a way to get live feed from an Android phone and seed it to a server. (like "ip camera" on android)

The main idea is to create a Kivy Android app that gets the camera feed to send it to my server that is processing and the storing that for later use.

Where should I start because all the information I can find is about using the app IP camera and the connecting the server to the apps IP address to process the information...

Comment: you should consider using WebSockets. On mobile app side first you connect to the websocket created by server. Now you capture the image and convert it to base64 string. Then you can transfer the image. At server side you decode the image string to numpy or suitable one.

Comment: Hi Epsi95 I know I have to use sockets and I understand the concept for images but how can I do the same for video?

Comment: Video is nothing but series of images. You capture process, then again capture and process

Comment: Hi can you get into a bit more details? Because how would you do the capture because the opencv does not work in Android with Buildozer...

Comment: have u checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62063847/is-there-a-way-to-record-videos-in-kivy

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful.